# posting data to controller from View not passing data, but it writes out a blank file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, post

Post gets me to the controller, but there is no data being passed... it will write out a blank file.
When I put a breakpoint in the controller - it breaks there , but there is no data. There are no error messages. It just writes out a blank file. Before the post, the data is in the variable being passed for data.

My controller code:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public void SavePresets(string theData)
 {
     System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/presets.json"));
     file.WriteLine(theData);
     file.Close();

     return;
}
```

My View code:

```
newJson = JSON.stringify(modifyJson);  // This is the Json I want to write out in the controller
console.log(newJson);  // Json shows up here and is good Json

$.ajax({
    url:"/Home/SavePresets/",  //this gets me to the controller above...
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: newJson,
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/jsonrequest; charset=utf-8"
});
```

My Json:

{"S1":{"x":0,"y":0,"z":0},"S2":{"x":130,"y":130,"z":130},"S3":{"x":300,"y":300,"z":400},"S4":{"x":200,"y":130,"z":40},"S5":{"x":121,"y":78,"z":55},"S6":{"x":56,"y":33,"z":92},"SHome":{"x":0,"y":0,"z":0}}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok answering my own question.

The ajax call should look like this:

```
$.post("/Home/SavePresets/", {theData: JSON.stringify(presetData)});
```

and the controller changes to:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SavePresets(string theData)
{
     if (theData != null)
     {
         System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/presets.json"));
         file.WriteLine(theData);
         file.Close();
      }
      return;
 }
```

Everything works fine now...